# Deserializing unrecognized json data into a Map JacksonJson

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, resttemplate

I have an example class

```
public class Category {
private String id ;
    private String name ;

private String description ;

private String image ;

private String thumbnail ;
 private Map<String, String> custom ;
}
```

I have a response from the server in the format below, but for example purpose let us say this is in a file cat.json

```
{"id":"mens","name":"Mens","c__showInMenu":true,"c__enableCompare":false}

   1 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); // can reuse, share globally
   2 Category cat= mapper.readValue(new File("cat.json"), Category.class);
```

This works perfectly fine for the fields id, name etc.
How do I write a custom deserializer such that any fields in the json starting with `c_` are pushed into the Map custom?

I am pretty new to Jackson and am using Springs Rest Template and configured it to use
`org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to simply make use of [`@JsonAnySetter`](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/07/entry_458.html).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAnySetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonMethod;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

public class JacksonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
  {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
    Category category = mapper.readValue(new File("cat.json"), Category.class);
    System.out.println(category);
    // output:
    // Category: id=mens, name=Mens, description=null, image=null, thumbnail=null, custom={c__showInMenu=true, c__enableCompare=false}
  }
}

class Category
{
  private String id;
  private String name;
  private String description;
  private String image;
  private String thumbnail;
  private Map<String, String> custom;

  @JsonAnySetter
  void addSomething(String name, String value)
  {
    if (custom == null) custom = new HashMap();
    custom.put(name, value);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString()
  {
    return String.format("Category: id=%s, name=%s, description=%s, image=%s, thumbnail=%s, custom=%s", 
        id, name, description, image, thumbnail, custom);
  }
}
```

Comment: The Solution   is perfect. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but the only way I can think off is far from being "clean and perfect".
**I would recommend to dig through Jackson documentation before using it, as a last measure**.

What you could do is to create a class with map field which will hold all properties of serialized object, like so:

```
public class CustomObject {
    private Map<String,Object> map;
}
```

That way Jackson could parse such objects:

```
{ map : {"id":"mens","name":"Mens","c__showInMenu":true,"c__enableCompare":false}}
```

Now, you still have undesired "map" wrapper, which would mess up deserialization. One solution could be to surround incoming JSON content with "{ map : " and closing tag "}".

That way Jackson will properly map your object, you will have a map of all properties and you can iterate over it, get check type thanks to `instanceof` and retrieve all data.

Once again, this might be not the best way to do it and you should try cleaner solutions first. I'm not an expert on Jackson, so I cannot point you in a better direction.